# .Net Core 3.1 MVC Web App - DbUpdateConcurrencyException when trying to update a record

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The other answers on here regarding this issue are to do with a missing primary key or id field. This is not the case here.

So in my edit functionality, I am trying to edit a record from my ASPNetUsers table (Identity table). However I'm getting the following error message after my code hits the SaveChanges() method:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1
> row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or
> deleted since entities were loaded. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
> understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Here is my controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string id, ApplicationUser applicationUser)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }      


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Entry(applicationUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    _context.Users.Update(applicationUser);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!MemberExists(applicationUser.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }

            return View(applicationUser);

        }
```

What I am trying to update is a row in the ASPNetUsers table. This is the table created when scaffolding microsoft identity into the project. See screenshot showing the values of the two passed in parameters.

[screenshot with values of parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zVLT.png)

Any tips would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Better to show SQL and your model configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this syntax:

```
      var existItem = await _context.Set<ApplicationUser>().FindAsync(applicationUser.Id);
        if (existItem == null)
        {
            //ErrorMessage = "Can't find item to update";
        }
            else
          {
                _context.Entry(existItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(applicationUser);
                var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
          }
```

Comment: Hi, that did indeed work for me. I'm trying to understand why my code didn't work but yours did. I've seen alot of tutorials use the EntitiyState.Modified method.

Comment: I never use Update in my EFs. It is only good for a "Hello world" samples in a textbook. When you select your item for a edit , your record is locked already and you have to change this record to unlock and save.